# Is there a way to use both a .testsettings and .runsettings file in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, mstest, code-coverage

I have an existing `.testsettings` file that is being used by Visual Studio for running tests.

We are starting to use the built-in code coverage tools with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Custom rules can be stored in a `.runsettings` file, and the project can be set to use that file in the Test > Test Settings > Select Test Settings menu.

Is there a way to use multiple settings files, since they have distinct purposes?  Or do `.testsettings` and `.runsettings` both fulfill the same purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have determined that you can only use one of these.  The [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx) lays out that `.runsettings` file is a newer version of `.testsettings`.  `.testsettings` uses the older MSTest framework, where `.runsettings` uses the newer multi-engine provider framework with newer versions of Visual Studio.